# Get revocation date using CRL and OCSP on iOS / Security.Framework

Tags: swift, x509certificate

Is there any possible way to get the revocation date of X509 certificate using the OCSP or CLR?I am able to check if the certificate is revoked or expired.

I use SecTrustEvaluateWithError to check the certificate if its expired or revoked.But I don't get back the revocation date.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.